# Openid Setup Incomplete issue

Tags: php, openid, openid-connect, janrain, openid-provider

I am facing the following problem when setting the openid connect from Janrain.

To test I have uploaded this on my server in following folder of my server:

```
/home/xyz/public_html/openid
```

When I run the detect file from example folder (/openid/examples/detect.php) it gives me following error:

```
OpenID Library Support Report

This script checks your PHP installation to determine if you are set up to use the JanRain PHP OpenID library.


Setup Incomplete

Your system needs a few changes before it will be ready to run the OpenID library.


Math support

Your PHP installation has gmp support. Good.
Cryptographic-quality randomness source

The library will try to access /dev/urandom as a source of random data. It seems to exist and be readable. Here is some hex data: 967ee0b38961.

Data storage

Support was found for mysql. The library supports the MySQL, PostgreSQL, and SQLite database engines, as well as filesystem-based storage. In addition, PEAR DB is required to use databases.

The open_basedir configuration restriction is not in effect.

If you are using the filesystem store, your data directory must be readable and writable by **mydomain** and not available over the Web.

HTTP Fetching

This PHP installation has support for libcurl. Good.

An HTTP request was completed. An unexpected URL was returned: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/chuckpearce/6810258/raw/c57eff55ebc0af5f72bac72762cf4f4/gistfile1.txt.

Your PHP installation appears to support SSL, so it will be able to process HTTPS identity URLs and server URLs.
XML Support

XML parsing support is present using the Auth_Yadis_dom interface.
Query Corruption

Your web server does not corrupt queries. Good.
```

I thought open_basedir could be problem, so i added the following code to my php.ini in public_html folder:

```
open_basedir = /home/xyz/public_html:/tmp
```

How can I get this fixed?

Also, I am using this outside codeigniter as a separate provider.

Thanks

Comment: Try running phpinfo() (http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) and see where your php.ini file is getting read from.  Chances are the php.ini file you are editing is not the one that is getting used.

Comment: This is what is get: Loaded Configuration File  /home/xyz/public_html/php.ini

Comment: It seems to me that the php.ini file is reading fine, anyhow I am thinking of removing the php.ini file i created in the file manager & editing the main file found in usr/lib of the server

Comment: Hi @PBJanrain I have made the changes to the relevant php.ini as sugested by you. Yet it says setup is incomplete. Any suggestions?

Comment: Following is what I get in data storage:

Support was found for mysql. The library supports the MySQL, PostgreSQL, and SQLite database engines, as well as filesystem-based storage. In addition, PEAR DB is required to use databases.

If you are using a filesystem-based store or SQLite, be aware that open_basedir is in effect. This means that your data will have to be stored in one of the following locations:

'/dir here/'

If you are using the filesystem store, your data directory must be readable and writable by <my domain user> and not available over the Web.

Comment: Sorry for the delay,  although I do work at Janrain, I don't really have that much experience with this particular library.  However looking at the code where that error message is coming back might help you:

https://github.com/openid/php-openid/blob/master/examples/detect.php#L354-L367   

Which has a link to:  http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php#ini.open-basedir

Which indicates that the setting has been deprecated in PHP 5.3.0 and removed in 5.4.0.  If you are using the latest PHP then I would go ahead and ignore that error and see what happens.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @PBJanrain Thank you for your kind reply. I can ignore that warning, what do you feel about the following line I get :  " If you are using the filesystem store, your data directory must be readable and writable by <my domain user> and not available over the Web."

Comment: It seems like you are fairly new to PHP. Your questions don't really have anything to do with OpenID or authentication. You should probably review some information on securing PHP sites.  I found this link that seems like a good starting point:  https://php.earth/doc/security/intro .  The PHP documentation for these settings also has lots of good information.

Comment: @PBJanrain Thanks for the help. Cheers